# DataTable to Crystal Report

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I'm trying to print the conents of DataGrid into CrystalReport by passing data from DGV to Datatable then to Crystal Report, it works but my problem is it only displays the first row in the crystal report... I need all the rows to be printed.. here's the code below:
'

```
    Dim dt_RadLogBook As New DataTable("dt_RadLogBook")
    With dt_RadLogBook
        .Columns.Add("CaseNumber")
        .Columns.Add("Name")
        .Columns.Add("BirthDate")
        .Columns.Add("PhilHealth Membership")
        .Columns.Add("Ward Name")
        .Columns.Add("Address")
        .Columns.Add("LMP")
    End With

    For Each dgr As DataGridViewRow In frmRadLogBook.dgvLogBook.Rows
        dt_RadLogBook.Rows.Add(dgr.Cells(0).Value, dgr.Cells(1).Value, dgr.Cells(2).Value, dgr.Cells(3).Value, dgr.Cells(4).Value, dgr.Cells(5).Value, dgr.Cells(6).Value)
        MsgBox(dgr.Cells(0).ToString)
    Next
    Dim rptDocument As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
    rptDocument = New rptRadLogBook1
    rptDocument.SetDataSource(dt_RadLogBook)
    frmReportForm.CRV1.ReportSource = rptDocument
    frmReportForm.ShowDialog()
```

'

Comment: How was the grid filled originally? Even if you start with an empty grid, create and bind a DataTable and you will avoid the slow messy For Each loop.

Comment: i filled it with dataset from sql query and i can see the rows displayed on the datagridview

Answer (score 0):

Instead of re-inventing the wheel, you can extract the DataSource from the DataGridView.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click, Button2.Click
    Dim dt = DirectCast(frmRadLogBook.dgvLogBook.DataSource, DataTable)
    Dim rptDocument As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
    rptDocument = New rptRadLogBook1
    rptDocument.SetDataSource(dt)
    frmReportForm.CRV1.ReportSource = rptDocument
    frmReportForm.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

I don't have Crystal Reports so I can not test the rest of the code.